# How do I determine a winner on this text-based game?

Tags: python

I made a working version of this game, player vs computer. I do not know how to determine a winner and after about 30 mins of research, I decided to ask here.

This is a simple game. The computer is randomised so there is no strategy within your opponent. I've tried to make the computer read the previous line to see who made the last move (as the opposite player wins) and I tried using subtraction. I haven't coded in the last 2 months so is there anything I'm missing?

```
    import random

    print("That pen game you used to play as a kid (it's kinda like 21 
    dares)")
    newnum = random.randint(20,30)
    print("Starting number: {}".format(newnum))
    while newnum > 0:
        pRemove = int(input("How many do you want to remove: "))
        if pRemove >= 1 and pRemove <= 3:
            newnum = newnum - pRemove
            print("{} left".format(newnum))
            if newnum <= 0:
                break
        elif pRemove > 3 or pRemove < 1:
            print("Put a number from 1-3")
            break
        else:
            print("error")
            exit()
        CPUremove = random.randint(1, 3)
        newnum = newnum - CPUremove
        print("CPU removed {}. {} left!".format(CPUremove, newnum))
```

At the end I need to see "You Win!" or "You Lose!" followed by the termination of the program. (I mean to add something to the end of it, not change the code)

Comment: Not sure what you are after here, what is the problem ?

Comment: What win condition do you want ? Is the goal to be the one to reach 0 or is it the opposit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `while` loop, set a variable:

```
human_went_last = False
while newnum > 0:
    ...
```

And in the check after the player removed some pens, set the variable to a new value:

```
        if newnum <= 0:
            human_went_last = True
            break
```

Then, after the loop, you can check who went last.

```
if human_went_last:
    print("Human made the last move")
else:
    print("Computer made the last move")
```